# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.2

Tags: javascript

so when trying to parse date from html source ima getting in "dd/mm/yyyy" which i need to convert to "yyyy/mm/dd" . im getting error as "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

i have tried the following code

```
string text = RegionProcessing.InnerText(context);
text = text.Replace("Offer Ends: ", "");  
DateTime userDate = DateTime.Parse(text);
context.SetOutputValue(userDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

Comment: Do you have any sample data? What **exactly** does `text` contain when it is parsed?

Comment: This does not look like JavaScript. Do you mean Java?